# Head detection using depth map

Tags: kinect, detection, head

This is my first interaction with kinect xbox, i have to count the number of people getting in and out from a door, what i have learned to do is to get a depth map, 
Detect the top of head closer to sensor and track it
Increment/decrement count when head crosses a specifuc region
I am able to get the depth image, but totally blank that how would detect head from depth image.
I am using xbox 360 kinect, and Kinect for windows SDK v1.8  in c# 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kinect SDK by default gives you the coordinates for body part tracking, such as the head. Also, the SDK can track up to 2 individual people (for Kinect v1 / SDK 1.8) and 6 different people (for Kinect v2 / SDK 2.0). 
For starters, you can get the location of the head as reported by the SDK and count when it crosses the region maybe? Simply search for Kinect Head tracking and you can see that it's easy to locate the head in a scene using the SDK (instead of a depth map directly). 
[An example for the 1.8 SKD is given here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you please mention the specific method names which may provide body parts coordinates?? and specific coordinates of head??

Comment: Well, I haven't worked exactly on body tracking using the Kinect, but more as a depth mapping device, but you might find this link (http://pterneas.com/2014/03/13/kinect-for-windows-version-2-body-tracking/) useful.